# Cancelling the previous called task using timer

Tags: android

I am using Timer for calling a method after 5 sec. When i call the same method again before 5 sec the previous called method should get cancelled. How to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not to re-initiate again Timer with TimerTask again. You can schedule it like this.

```
//Declare the timer
Timer t = new Timer();
//Set the schedule function and rate
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period parameter)
    }

},
//Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
0,
//Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
1000);
```

If you need to cancel timer any time, you can use this.

```
timer.cancel();  // Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks.
timer.purge();   // Removes all cancelled tasks from this timer's task queue.
```

Comment: when i call it again the previous called method should get cancelled @Khemraj

Comment: Write your all code with the method so i can tell you.